# Error : invalid operands to binary ^ (have 'float' and 'int' )

Tags: c, function, codeblocks

i'm doing a code using function, but when i try to run it i have the error "invalid operands to binary ^ (have 'float' and 'int' )". The operation that i want to do is: Vo*((1-(1+I)^-N)/I).     Here's the code. Thanks!

```
#include <stdlib.h>

float func(int anios, float tipointeres){

    float interes_mod, func, porcen;
    int n=0;

    porcen = tipointeres/100; //El interes es porcentaje, así que hacemos esto para que sea uno.

    for(n;n<anios;n++){

         interes_mod = (1+porcen)^(-anios);
         func = ((1-interes_mod)/porcen);

    }
       return func;
}





int main()
{
    int anios;
    float valortotal, constrenta, tipointeres;

    printf("Ingresa el importe constante de la renta (Vo): ");
    scanf("%f", &constrenta);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Ingresa el tipo de interes (I): ");
    scanf("%f", &tipointeres);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Ingresa el numero de años (N): ");
    scanf("%d", &anios);
    fflush(stdin);


    valortotal = func(anios, tipointeres)* constrenta; //Aquí multplico Vo por toda la fracción.


    printf("El valor actual de la renta es: %f", valortotal);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ^ is the exclusive-or operator, and your equation doesn't look like that's what you want (hint: take a look at the pow() function in math.h)

Comment: C is not a language you can successfully use by typing in stuff you guess will work.  Please do yourself a favor and read through at least the first few chapters of a good introductory book or tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

The `^` operator is *not* the power operator but the **bitwise XOR** operator.  This operator expects both operands to be integer types, which is why you're getting the error.

To perform exponentiation you want the `pow` or `powf` function, which raises the first argument to the power of the second.  In your case you'll want to use the latter since you're only using `float` as opposed to `double`:

```
interes_mod = powf(1+porcen,-anios);
```

Note that you'll also need to `#include <math.h>` to get the declaration of the function and compile with the `-lm` flag to link in the math library.

Comment: @AndresGards Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.